# php:7.4-fpm-alpine - Invalid configuration `gd': machine `gd-unknown' not recognized

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, fpm

I'm trying to get work a `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` image, but a get this error in build time:

```
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `gd': machine `gd-unknown' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh build/config.sub gd failed
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache libzip-dev     && docker-php-ext-configure zip gd     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) zip pdo pdo_mysql' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile code is:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apk update && apk add  --no-cache \
    libmcrypt \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    freetype \
    freetype-dev \
    libpng \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo \
    libzip-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev g++ make autoconf \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) zip pdo pdo_mysql
```

Can help me?

Comment: Every example you find of installing GD support (there are many thousands here on SO), [including the example in the Docker PHP docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/php), also installs support for some image formats, eg various `libjpeg` and/or `libpng` versions.  It makes sense those might be required, as GD is an image lib. Is there a reason you are not installing any?  Have you tried with those included?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes, before I tried including those but keeping giving the same error, whatever, now edit the image to include image libraries as documentation advises.

Answer (score -1):

Fix

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html


RUN apk add --no-cache \
    freetype \
    libpng \
    libjpeg-turbo \
    freetype-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype \
    --with-jpeg \ 
    && NPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1) && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j${NPROC} gd && \
    apk del --no-cache freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```